# How to prevent images from moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this example where I wanted to demonstrate my problem: https://codepen.io/Kapaak/pen/oNBbgad

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #01383a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #f5c1a0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.wrapper h2 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .image {
  width: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper .image.bottom-left {
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.wrapper .image.top-right {
  top: 4rem;
  right: 4rem;
}

.wrapper .image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Some random headline text</h2>
  <div class="image top-right">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611412570995-ed61b6e2f098?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYxNjY4NTk1Nw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image bottom-left">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611412570995-ed61b6e2f098?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYxNjY4NTk1Nw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make some page, where will be some interactive images, that will be positioned somewhere on the page, just like the cats in the codepen. The problem is that when you resize window, they will always retain the same position.

What I want is to give them lets say max-width:900 and when I have smaller width they wont move, they will just overflow the page and I want the headline to be centered, thats why I gave the images position:absolute

Comment: No I want the images to be just somewhere on the best, it doesnt matter, what matters is that the title needs to be centered. Yes I know that the right:4rem puts it alway 4rem from the corner and this is where I dont know how to solve it

Comment: Ok I tried the left:104rem and it works, ye I didnt realise it, thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your right image is moving when you resize the browser is because you made it absolute compared to the right edge with `right: 4rem;`. If you change that value to say `left: 104rem;` then it will always be positioned 104 rem from the left edge of the window, regardless of the window width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #01383a;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #f5c1a0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.wrapper h2 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .image {
  width: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper .image.bottom-left {
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 4rem;
}

.wrapper .image.top-right {
  top: 4rem;
  left: 104rem;
}

.wrapper .image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Some random headline text</h2>
  <div class="image top-right">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611412570995-ed61b6e2f098?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYxNjY4NTk1Nw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image bottom-left">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611412570995-ed61b6e2f098?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxNDU4OXwwfDF8cmFuZG9tfHx8fHx8fHx8MTYxNjY4NTk1Nw&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to either use Bootstrap columns (https://getbootstrap.com/), as these dynamically resize images/text in columns. Or you can use the following css to keep the same position.

```
#image {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin-left:50%;
 margin-right:50%;
 position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: That bootstrap solution is interesting yet I dont use bootstrap or jquery :D. Nevertheless I have found out that instead of seting  .top-right{ right:4rem} I can just simply set left:100rem and it will do the thing.   @WOUNDEDStevenJones you were correct

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resize images when the page size is decreased you can use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) in CSS. These can also be used to change the properties of any element for any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your title always be centered use

> text-align: center;

on your h2 element